# Embedding matplotlib in tkinter: return focus to canvas after listbox event and reconnect toolbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Below you find the [Embedding matplotlib in tkinter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) example with the slight change that a Listbox widget is added.

When I click a listbox entry the focus is on the listbox and the canvas and toolbar key events are disconnected (clicking the toolbar buttons still works, but not keyboard shortcuts, arrow keys etc.).

I can restore the focus by pressing the 'Tab' key twice but I want for this to happen **automatically**, so the user doesn't get confused why the matplotlib keys don't work anymore after selection and then has to try hitting 'Tab' until they're back.

Generating 'Tab' events (commented out in the code below) does *not* even work, but is anyway not desired. In my real GUI, you'd have to hit 'Tab' even more often, very annoying.

I'd prefer something like `canvas.get_tk_widget().focus()`, but it also doesn't work and the related posts for text widgets were not helping.

Is it the wrong widget? Or the wrong focus function?

I played with several focus and grab functions but without luck. So, thanks a lot for your help!

```py
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root, pack_toolbar=False)
toolbar.update()

canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", lambda event: print(f"you pressed {event.key}"))
canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", key_press_handler)

# add listbox 
def on_listbox_select(event):
    # do stuff according to selection
    print(listbox.curselection())
    # return focus to canvas - not working!
    canvas.get_tk_widget().focus()
    #root.event_generate('<Tab>')
    #root.event_generate('<Tab>')
    return("break")

listbox = tkinter.Listbox(root, selectmode='extended', activestyle='none')
for ii in range(5): listbox.insert(tkinter.END, 'Entry ' + str(ii))
listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", on_listbox_select)
listbox.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, anchor='nw')

button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=root.quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

toolbar.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, fill=tkinter.X)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.focus_set()` instead of `.focus()` and then using `<ButtonRelease>` as the event instead of `<<ListboxSelect>>` worked for me.

I think the reason that `<<ListboxSelect>>` didn't work is because the event is sent right as you click, however after that event is sent you're still holding down your mouse button for a fraction of a second, nevertheless long enough to focus on the `listbox` widget again.

Full lines just in case:

```
canvas.get_tk_widget().focus_set()
...
listbox.bind("<ButtonRelease>", on_listbox_select)
```

Comment: I was suspecting some timing issue before and played unsuccessfully with the tkinter after() function to delay the focus change. Using ButtonRelease instead does the trick!